# RSA vs ECDSA for VANET Security

Tags: cryptography, digital-signature

I am doing a project on Vehicular Ad-Hoc Network Security (VANET). The proposed scheme uses electronic signature as a means to authenticating the nodes. Most of the research papers I read suggested ECDSA because it says a "160 bit key in ECC is as secure as 1024 bit key in RSA, and is faster and occupies less memory" But on the other hand I also read that verification time of RSA is significantly lower. So won't RSA be a better choice since the vehicles would be travelling at high speeds and we should concentrate on keeping verification time lower?

Comment: Does the downvoter feel like gracing us with a comment, are are they just intent on being an unhelpful asshat?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, signature *generation* time is more critical, because signature generation entails using private keys, which must be protected, and therefore used in shielded system which trade security for computing power. E.g. smart cards.

In an overall system, it may happen that RSA is better than ECDSA, or the contrary. For an ad hoc network, we might expect that components authenticate *each other*, which implies that the relevant measure is the *sum* of the signature generation time and the signature verification time. For that sum, ECDSA wins over RSA. It also offers *shorter* signatures, which is a great asset on low-bandwidth networks.